# Placing Header Location as Sql Die action

Tags: php, mysql, header

I was curious to know if i could do this, but found no examples on line

```
$info_find = mysql_query("SELECT info FROM sets WHERE category = '$selected_cat'")  
or die( header ("location: index.php"));
```

Firstly doing it as above doesn't work. Can it be done?
Are there any drawbacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

die() just writes its parameter out, it doesn't execute it. So a "or die()" construct will not help you there.

You can consider something like

```
or die(createRedirect("index.php"));
```

with

```
function createRedirect($where) {
  $s='<html><head>';
  $s.='<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url='.$where.'">';
  $s.='</head><body>If you are not automatically redirected click <a href="'.$where.'">here</a>';
  $s.='</body></html>';
  return $s;
}
```

if you are willing to accept the downsides of client-sided redirection

Comment: Thanks I think the fact that die works like an echo was the Answer. THanks also for your suggested work around.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your code as

```
$info_find = mysql_query("SELECT info FROM sets WHERE category = '$selected_cat'")  ;
if ($info_find === FALSE) {
  header ('location: index.php');
  die();
}
```

But, before use the header function, be sure you haven't send any output to the browser.